# How do I add a raster texture file to Illustrator's 3D Extrude & Bevel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, 3d, texture

How do I get an image to extrude and bevel using illustrator CS6.

The shape that's having the issues has effect>texture>texturizer and then I uploaded a psd file.

When I then select effects>3d>extrude bevel I get a giant grey box around the image.

I've also tried using the textures that are already in Ai but the same gray box appears.

Ugh it won't let me screenshot because I'm a newb but picture the flat, now textured shape, lying on the 3D grey box that adheres to the specifications chosen in the bevel/extrude window.

If this is not possible I guess I'm asking what's the best way to add a texture to an image I want to make 3D?

Comment: Any chance you're running out of memory?

Comment: Are you trying to extrude a raster image with a clipping mask perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

> ....but picture the flat, now textured shape, lying on the 3D grey box that adheres to the specifications chosen in the bevel/extrude window.

You need to do things differently if this is what you are after.

- Import your raster texture file. You **must** embed the image. Linking to it will not work.
- Drag the raster image to the Symbol Panel to create a symbol if it. Afterwards you can delete the raster image *on the artboard*. You only need the symbol.
- draw a rectangle
- choose `Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel` and set the rectangle up how you want it.
- Click the **Map Art** button in the 3D effect window.
- Pick the correct side of the rectangle from the little arrows Where it reads **Surface** at the top of the window. Light shapes mean visible, dark shapes mean hidden (behind other sides).
- Choose the Symbol containing the raster image you just made
- Size or rotate the the symbol how you want it.

[image: map]

[image: sized]

Note: if you are trying to get depth directly within the raster image via Illustrator's 3D effect, you will not be able to. It simply does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here that you're having is that the original psd file has layer styles already applied to it, you really want to flatten the image completely before trying to use the "Extrude and Bevel" technique on illustrator.

To do this open up your .psd and find the layer that it is you wish to extrude. Make a new layer underneath this and then reselect the layer above, right click and "merge down" your image will now be flattened and upon reopening with illustrator, should now be functional with the technique you wish to use.

Failing this you can always extrude and bevel the shape style you want to texture, copy this and paste into a psd as a smart object. Then with some use of blending layers and transformations of the size and perspective of your texture layer (placed above the object layer) you should be able to create the illusion of a texture on a 3d object.